# Mahout Clustering CSV to List<Vector>

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout

I'm really new to Mahout (and Java - my boss asked me to learn them both at the same time), so the more basic the explanation the better! I'm trying to run KMeansClusterer (not Driver), which means I'll need to get a CSV (all values are doubles) to a List Vector.

I came across this explanation
[Mahout: CSV to vector and running the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663567/mahout-csv-to-vector-and-running-the-program/15003316#15003316) but I'm not really sure how to use it (I don't think it applies to me).

Can anyone help me either with the syntax for CSVVectorIterator or with whatever I'll need to get a CSV into a usable format?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific in what exactly you need help in? Seems pretty broad.

Comment: I'm using "Mahout in Action" and the only examples in the book for clustering use randomly generated data sets. I have a CSV in the right format (data points' attributes are in columns, rows are different data points). To use the clusterer, my data needs to be in a List Vector. I don't know how to get a CSV into that format. 

The recommender engines use DataModel to get data stored in a CSV and I was hoping there was a similar way to do that in the clustered.